# How to make page with image and text in header responsive?

Tags: css, blazor, bootstrap-5, .net-6.0

I have a razor page with a header. The header is a component PageHeader.razor.
And I try it to make responsive. But when I show it in the responsive mode the text and image are overlapping eachother.

What do I wrong?

The page with the header:

```
<div class="row myheader">
    @{
        string title = "This is a title";
        string subtitle = "This is a subtitle";
        <PageHeader Title=@title Subtitle=@subtitle />
    }
</div>
```

... and the header:

```
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="col-2 me-0">
            @{
                string url = $"/images/trofee.png";
                <img src=@url class="rounded float-start image-responsive" height="256" width="256" />
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 ms-0 rounded mb-3 align-self-end text-start">
            <div class="row mytitleheader">
                <h2><span>@Title</span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row mysubtitleheader">
                <span>@Subtitle</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public string Subtitle { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public string ImageType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

... and the css:

```
.myheader {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, yellow, orange); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, yellow, orange); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, yellow, orange); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, orange); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px black;
    margin: 4px 7px 25px 4px;
}

.mytitleheader {
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: italic;
}

.mysubtitleheader {
    font-style: italic;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

Examples from the small and larges view:

[image]
and:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because you set `col-2` for `img` parent and it sets `width:16.666%`. Just delete it if you want `img` parent to be 256x256.

```
<div class="me-0">
         @{
              string url = $"/images/trofee.png";
              <img src=@url class="rounded float-start image-responsive" height="256" width="256" />
          }
</div>
```